# On new (purely analytic) perspective towards theory of prime numbers

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, prime-number-theorem

[I'm going to ask this question very carefully as a question similar to this received a critical response on this platform.
I myself am very skeptical about this but I want to know, from the experts' point of view, why this approach is not practical (if it is).]

Consider the following partial sum :

$$S(t)=\sum_{n=2}^t\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(n)}{2n}\right)$$

As we can see, the summand is zero for non-primes greater than 5 and finite non-decreasing for primes (see [Alain Connes paper on Wilson's theorem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.02832&ved=2ahUKEwjd4Y7csPznAhU4H7cAHe48APoQFjAAegQIBhAC&usg=AOvVaw1sYdzCHfHtkkmaO6ClRpfz).) So,we can use this as prime counting function in some approximate sense.

Due to analyticity of gamma function (and it's decay wrt imaginary part of complex variable) I treated this summation with Finite version Abel-Plana Summation Formula (APSF) (as in [Olver's book "Asymptotics and special functions"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://books.google.com/books/about/Asymptotics_and_Special_Functions.html%3Fid%3D-UBZDwAAQBAJ%26source%3Dkp_book_description&ved=2ahUKEwimyoLysPznAhV_4XMBHdxIDi8QmhMwBnoECA8QIw&usg=AOvVaw0c-orqzOtWgH8jDMAW85ZI)) (summand follows all the properties required by APSF) :

$$\begin{align}f(x) = {} & \sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(x)}{2x}\right)\\
\sum_{k=2}^t f(k)= {} & \frac{f(2) +f(t)}2 + \int_2^t f(x) \, dx \\ & {}+ i\int_0^∞\frac{f(2+iy) − f(2−iy)}{e^{2πy }− 1} \, dy +i \int_0^∞\frac{f(t-iy) − f(t+iy)}{e^{2πy }− 1} \, dy\end{align}$$

Here the first integral $∫f(x)dx$ is okay (highly oscillatory but we can do something: at least numerically)

Now, to analyze the following integral

$$i \int_0^∞\frac{f(t-iy) − f(t+iy)}{e^{2πy }− 1} \,dy ,$$

I tried to get a growth condition on it without much success.

So, I tried to attach a weight such that this integral is convergent to zero as $t\rightarrow\infty$ :

$$F(z) = \omega(z)\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(z)}{2z}\right)$$

The following three condition should hold for $ω(z)$ :

1. $$ω(z)>\frac{1}{z}, \quad \forall z∈R$$ and it is analytic for $\Re(z)>2$ 
   (More generally this condition is added to impose the divergence of $\int_2^{+\infty} F(x)dx$. So $ω(z)$ can even be complex valued for real domain as long as the given integral is divergent (to prove infinitude of prime by this method) we can make various other generalizations.)
2. $$\lim_{y→∞}|F(x±iy)|e^{−2πy}=0$$
3. $$∫_0^∞|F(x+iy)−F(x−iy)|e^{−2πy}dy<+∞$$
   for every $x≥1$ and tends to zero as $x→∞$.

This is to eliminate the tricky 2nd integral in the formula.

We can also use some operators on $f(x)$ with preserving prime counting property in order to eliminate 2nd integral like:

Instead of finding the weight ; consider sin^2 term as function of some other function such that:

Construct a generalized function such that:

$$F_∗(z)=\varphi(\sin^2[πΓ(z)/(2z)])$$

1. $\varphi(x)=0$ if $x$ is zero ; and 'suitably' finite otherwise
   (Here , 'suitably' means a value which guarantees the expected divergence of sum (very close to 1 or greater than or equal to 1) )
2. conditions (2) and (3) above holds for such function

Possible candidate: I'm studying this test function for above analysis(at least numerically):

$ F(z,s) = \dfrac{1}{z^s\Gamma(\sin^2[π\Gamma(z)/(2z)])} $.

And let us restrict $s\in[0,1]$

My question :

> Is this approach worth further study? If anything wrong with the analysis, please state.
> Any comments in the directive manner are welcome.

> Can we get an estimate on summation $S(t)$ using the above method? ( Estimate as strong as prime number theorem or more stronger)

> At its most generality, what can we derive from this approach which is already known about prime numbers (or more than what we know)?

(I've done verious generalizations of this approach but I'm going to keep this short )

Moreover we can generalize this approach as follows :

Consider the following function :

$$T(x)=w(x)\frac{\sin^2(c \frac{\Gamma^2(x)}{x})}{\sin^2(\frac{c}{x})}$$

As we can see, for $c=π$ and finite $w(x)$, $T(x)$ is 0 for non-prime $x$ and 1 for prime $x$.

Now if we consider $w(x)$ as rational  function s.t. $\sum_{p}w(p)$ converges and second (complex) integral (Only $T(t)$ instead of $f(t)$) in above analysis converges to zero as t tends to infinity.

Then we can prove the infinitude of primes by computing the first real integral and proving that it is irrational (extremely hard).

I'm very much skeptical about this approach, but I thought about it so i added a description.

The reason I'm interested in infinitude of primes is that; if possible ,such method can be extended to twin primes and other forms of primes whose infinitude is unknown.

Possible Unified Applications: We can apply it to other primes of special forms whose Infinitude is unknown. (as Γ is nicely analytic).

Example:

$$S_2(p)=\sum_{n=2}^p\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(n)}{2n}\right)\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(n+2)}{2(n+2)}\right)$$

A question with same essence is on Math Stack Exchange for more than a year with no response. I also corresponded with various professors about this with not much of help from anyone :

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570663/789323

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question could be improved if you explain better what you are trying to do. Are you trying to estimate the sum $S(p)$ to obtain better bounds for the prime-counting function?

Comment: @WillSawin yes sir I'm trying to estimate the sum. (Also forgive my english it's not my first language so I can't properly explain it but I'll try)

Comment: To me, it seems likely that the function you are integrating oscillates too rapidly to get a good estimate for the sum by any straightforward manipulation. But I have no proof that this won't work, or even any strong evidence, so I didn't say anything. I would guess most people have neither an idea to make your strategy work nor a convincing argument that it won't work, and thus don't have much to say  in response.

Comment: The gamma function is not entire. It has simple poles at nonpositive integers.

Comment: @WillSawin I completely agree with you sir. But, the interest in this approach is due to the analyticity of gamma function in RHP and f(x)'s properties satisfying Abel Plana Summation. Instead of getting estimate; we can think globally as mentioned in the above analysis: find a suitable weight s.t. the second (complex) integral in the APSF converges to zero(or atleast controlled growth wrt real integral) and real one diverges as p→∞ ; in this way we can prove infinitude of various suitable(satisfying APSF) forms of primes ( if works)

Comment: *Here the first integral is okay (highly oscillatory but we can do something: at least numerically)*  Maybe you should post the "something" that you can do.

Comment: Up to version 14 of this question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry for that, but I always tend to correct my mistakes and update the post as I progress.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to correct the mistakes before you post, or correct them all at once instead of one at a time.

Comment: Please do not spam me by intentionally notifying me multiple times asking if I have anything to comment.

Comment: @WillSawin sorry sir

Comment: I want to explain in detail why Will Sawin(not tagging him because of his comment) thinks I'm spamming him. I made big Feb 17 8:17 comment. In that comment I first I made mistake by stating gamma is entire which I corrected ; and again observed that I have written 'ABSF' instead of 'APSF' which also I corrected and one more such mistake in other comment. but as we know we can't edit comment after 5 minutes I have to rewrite the comment. Also I'm using MO on my mobile so can't notice small mistakes properly. Again sorry because he felt offended.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @DanieleTampieri

Comment: Please explain downvotes!

Comment: I believe this question is showing signs of spiraling out of control just as the linked MSE question did - the dangers being (1) an excessive number of minor edits and (2) an excessive number of "get-every-thought-down" edits. Please make sure to keep the number of edits reasonable and the question as focused as possible.

Comment: Now version 19.

Comment: At this point it would probably be better to take a break from editing. The trouble is that each edit bumps your question to the head of the list, at the expense of other questions, and in this way it's bringing negative attention to itself (as I can verify as a moderator by looking at flags on the question). I don't know if this is a reason for downvotes, but I think Noah's advice is sound.

Comment: @ToddTrimble thank you sir, I'll keep that in mind

Comment: On MO nearly after 9 months, anything new on article?