# On a Duality between Riemann-weil explicit formula and Abel- Plana summation of trigonometric prime counting function:

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function

Consider the analytic function $g(x)$

Now define

> $f(x)=g(x)\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(x)}{2x}\right)}{\cos^2\left(\frac{π}{2x}\right)}$

Such that

> $|f(x+it)|=o(e^{2πt})$

uniformly for every $x$ ( Necessary condition for the use of finite version of  Abel Plana summation as in [Olver's book "Asymptotics and special functions"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://books.google.com/books/about/Asymptotics_and_Special_Functions.html%3Fid%3D-UBZDwAAQBAJ%26source%3Dkp_book_description&ved=2ahUKEwimyoLysPznAhV_4XMBHdxIDi8QmhMwBnoECA8QIw&usg=AOvVaw0c-orqzOtWgH8jDMAW85ZI))

Note that:

$f(p)=g(p)$ for prime p

And $f(n)=0$ for non prime integer n

Also,

> $\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(x+it)}{2(x+it)}\right)}{\cos^2\left(\frac{π}{2(x+it)}\right)}=o(1)$ uniformly for every x .

Now consider Riemann's explicit formula:

> $$\pi(x) = \operatorname{R}(x) - \sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R}(x^{\rho}) - \frac1{\ln x} + \frac1\pi \arctan \frac\pi{\ln x} $$

Here,
$\operatorname{R}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ \mu (n)}{n} \operatorname{li}(x^{1/n})$

Now by Stieltjes Integral:

> $\int_a^bg(x)d(π(x))=\sum_{a\leq{p}\leq{b}}g(p)$

i.e. the integral counts $g$-weighted primes

Now consider the following two equations:

> Eq1:
> $\int_5^bg(x)d(π(x))=\sum_{5\leq{p}\leq{b}}g(p)==\sum_{5\leq{n}\leq{b}}f(n)$

($π(x)$ is as mentioned above)

> Eq2: Finite version of Abel- Plana Summation on f(x):

> $$APS^b(f(x))=\sum_{k=5}^{[b]} f(k)=\frac{f(5) +f([b])}2 + \int_5^{[b]} f(x) \, dx + \\i\int_0^∞\frac{f(5+iy) − f(5−iy)}{e^{2πy }− 1} \, dy +i \int_0^∞\frac{f([b]-iy) - f([b]+iy)}{e^{2πy }− 1} \, dy
> $$

Note that [•] is greatest integer function

Now Note that

> Eq(1)=Eq(2) (explicit equality/duality)

i.e.

> $$\int_5^b g(x)\left(\operatorname{R}(x) - \frac1{\ln x} + \frac1\pi \arctan \frac\pi{\ln x}\right)'dx - APS^b(f(x))=\int_5^b g(x)\sum_{\rho}\operatorname{R'}(x^{\rho})dx$$

Here , what we have done is creating a duality between two (seemingly) different pieces of information ( prime sieving by zeta zeros and prime sieving by gamma function) using two different methods or tools ( Stieltjes Integral  and Abel Plana )
Here we can see everything  as linear operator/s working on $g(x)$

Even though the trig function behaves very wildly and very very hard to compute,the equality with explicit formula of Riemann is explicit and trig function sum in form of Abel Plana has analytically good enough terms

so I expect that in equivalent operator theoretical sense it's possible ,after suitable transformation of course, to get info about zeta zeros !?

LHS contains info about primes in alternative (but in analytic) way  than in explicit formula of Riemann
and RHS contains info about zeta zeros. So I have following questions.

Questions:

> Can we derive anything about non trivial zeros from above explicit duality?

> Is it possible to transform the given equation as operator theory problem/ eigenvalue problem ?

Also any advice on how to go further with this approach are welcome and also let me know if not worth to work on it.

Also we can note the following application of Able Plana (infinite version)

Now consider $f(x)$ as defined above with one more constraint as follows:

> $$-i\int_0^\infty\mathrm dt \frac{f(x + \mathrm it) − f(x −\mathrm it)}{\mathrm e^{2πy}-1}=o(1)$$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$

Or more strongly

> $|f(z)|<\frac{C}{|z|^{1+\epsilon}}$ for any $\epsilon$ and $C$

Now we can see that

> $$\sum_{k=5}^{\infty} g(k)  =\sum_{k=5}^{\infty} f(k)=\frac{f(5)}2 + \int_5^{\infty} f(x) \, dx + \\i\int_0^∞\frac{f(5+iy) − f(5−iy)}{e^{2πy }− 1} \, dy 
> $$

i.e. here we can calculate explicit constants/values for infinite sum of function of prime but $g(x)$ with above properties is very very rapidly decaying ;so not of apparent use I think.

(Also if anything wrong with the analysis please correct me I'm just a student )

Tbh I'm highly doubtful about all this

Comment: There are a few similar question posed by a user with a different name so maybe that's why people are confused; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3570663/towards-a-new-proof-of-infinitude-of-primes-with-possible-unified-application and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383467/on-new-purely-analytic-perspective-towards-theory-of-prime-numbers

Comment: Excellent - maybe it would be good to note that you posted similar stuff and now you try something somewhat different because if multiple similar questions appear it gets confusing

Comment: @Conrad thanks! As you mentioned, in this question I'm trying to maintain a relationship between zeros of Zeta and the funtionals from trigonometric prime counting function which I didn't tried in my previous questions

Comment: I'm a bit confused. First you indicate $\int_a^b g(x)\, d(\pi(x))=\sum_{a\leq{p}\leq{b}}g(p)$, but later you seem to use $\int_a^b g(x)\, \pi(x)\, dx$ instead of $\int_a^b g(x)\, \pi'(x)\, dx$.

Comment: @StevenClark thank you for correcting me. Kept everything general as I don't know if it works out or not

Comment: Could you please give a section and/or page reference for Abel Plana finite summation in your referenced book? The only version I've been able to find on the Internet is $$\sum\limits_{n=x}^y a(n)\, \phi(n)=A(y) \phi (y)-A(x) \phi(x)-\int\limits_x^y A(u) \, d\phi(u)$$ where $$A(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^x a(n)$$ (see [Abel's_summation_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula)).

Comment: I don't understand how your formula for $APS^b(f(x))$ follows from $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n)=\frac{f(0)}{2}+\int\limits_0^{\infty } f(x) \, dx+i \int\limits_0^{\infty } \frac{f(i t)-f(-i t)}{e^{2 \pi  t}-1} \, dt$$ (see [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula)). For example, shouldn't $\frac{f(5)+f([b])}2$ be $\frac{f(5)-f([b])}2$? Also, your formula doesn't seem to be consistent with $\sum\limits_{k=5}^{[b]} f(n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k+5)-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k+[b]+1)$.

Comment: @StevenClark The formula is correct (finite version). The infinite version follow from finite version. I mentioned a reference in the beginning of the post ( proof of this formula uses calculus of residues). Also Abel summation is different from Abel Plana.

Comment: The equivalence of your formula with [NIST DLMF formula 2.10.2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10) is not obvious to me. You referenced a book, but in an earlier comment I requested a more specific reference (section and/or page number).

Comment: Does the validity of $APS^b(f(x))$ depend on the convergence of $APS^\infty(f(x))$? You selected $g(x)$ such that $f(x)=g(x)\, \frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi\, \Gamma(x)}{2 x}\right)}{\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2 x}\right)}$ has certain properties which also seem to depend on $\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi\, \Gamma(x)}{2 x}\right)}{\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2 x}\right)}$, but how do you know that $\int\limits_5^\infty g(x)\,d(π(x))=\underset{P\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{5\leq{p}\leq{P}}g(p)\right)$ converges?